# Trouble Running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11 Surface Book 2: Trying to the green and blue part to match my instructor's

Tags: 20.04, username, troubleshooting

I am taking the Google IT Support Specialist course on Google, I am using Ubuntu 20.04, with a Surface Book 2, with Windows 11 capability,  and I need help with trying to get my code to follow that of Cindy the instructor. This for Course 3 in OS Week 1 "Linux Changing Directories in Bash".

So in a nutshell, I am trying to get my code to say something like "Hecto@DESTKOP...:~/Desktop$" and return "home/Hecto/Desktop" how do that?

I am trying set my Linux code to where it says "~/Desktop" like Cindy's? Do you have any suggestions as to how I should do this (i.e. give this [image: 1] a similar format as this [image: 2]?

If your suggestions is to change my current username "kdx264" back to the one  on my computer under my Desktop "Hecto",  I just want to let you know that I am having trouble with that because when I try to log into to a temporary account that I created for sudo like on this YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUK710T2M_w), it sates that "System has not been booted with systemmd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down Failed to talk to init daemon". Do you know what that even means in laymen terms? Any help would be appreciated. In fact, I am actually pretty novice at IT stuff.

Comment: Firstly, that's not code and you're not coding anything. Secondly, what you have to do to make it say `~/Desktop` is _change directory_, which is the topic of that lesson.

Comment: And something else, "see ps(1)" means look in the manual volume 1 for the ps command.  At the command line you usually have the manual pages installed,  run `man 1 ps` (and not "ps(1)").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using WSL, which will NEVER match what your instructor is using if they're using pure linux.  Your instructor looks to be using an Ubuntu Linux system - either in a VM or directly installed on their system.

It also will never properly give you a valid reply for process id 1 (which is init or systemd) because this is WSL and not a full Ubuntu installation.

I can tell you that based on the font differences and background of the terminal process and the coloring that your instructor or person named 'cindy' is, in fact, using an Ubuntu Desktop installation - either bare metal or virtualized - for their actions.  To match exactly, you will need to do a full installation of Ubuntu in a VM (via virtualbox or similar), or dual boot with Ubuntu which is a little finnicky with Windows 11 because of some of the things Windows 11 asserts on a computer.

My advice would be run an Ubuntu Desktop VM via VirtualBox on your system if you really want a fully functional Ubuntu installation rather than the semi-sorta-usable WSL that will not work with the base init processes.

Comment: Hi, Thomas. I think I am going to take your advice and install a full version. So, when I installed this wsl version it asked me to create an account.  I think I am going to end up deleting this account and creating a new one.  If I decide to uninstall the ubuntu 20.04 will the temporary account I created be deleted automatically? If not, would you happen to know how I could delete it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get the text to match rather than the color scheme. Because you say in the question:

> This for Course 3 in OS Week 1 "Linux Changing Directories in Bash".
>
> So in a nutshell, I am trying to get my code to say something like
> "Hecto@DESTKOP...:~/Desktop$" and return "home/Hecto/Desktop" how do
> that?

I haven't used WSL but the following should work on Ubuntu:

You need to change your working directory to "Desktop"

To do that type this:

```
cd Desktop
```

It is possible that the 'Desktop' directory does not exist, in which case you can do this:

```
mkdir Desktop
cd Desktop
```

[image]

Comment: Given the Bash prompt shown in the question (in the screenshot), `pwd` won't return  *home/Hecto/Desktop*.